# concat one file first in gulp

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I build my project with gulp, into a file called *all.js*.
In my workspace I have one file which I call *modules.js*. In this file I declare all of my namespaces.
I would like gulp to concat this file first, at the top of *all.js*, and only then the rest of the js files. This way I don't have to worry about files order, and any namespace being not defined.

Here is what I have tried:

```
gulp.src("./src/main/modules.js")
    .pipe(concat("all.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.src(["./src/**/*.js", "!./src/main/modules.js"]))
    .pipe(concat("all.js"))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dist));
```

But this way, *modules.js* is all that I see in *all.js*. the rest of the files are not being written at all.

How can I tell gulp to write *modules.js* into *all.js* first, and then add the rest of the js files after it?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use src after your concat. Use src first and add you modules.js at first followed by the rest of the scripts to make sure it works.

So `gulp.src([path-to-modules.js, path-to-rest])`

After that concat all and your modules.js will be on top.

Comment: Thanks!! works just fine. 
I wonder how it knows not to concat modules.js twice, though..

Answer (score 1):

There is a way to specify the concatenation order (using 'order') in gulp:

```
gulp
  .src("**/*.coffee")
  .pipe(coffee())
  .pipe(gulp.src("**/*.js")) // gulp.src passes through input 
  .pipe(order([
    "vendor/js1.js",
    "vendor/**/*.js",
    "app/coffee1.js",
    "app/**/*.js"
  ]))
  .pipe(concat("all.js"))
  .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"));
```

as explained in [npm documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order) and [this good article](https://martinwolf.org/blog/2014/08/force-a-concatenation-order-with-gulp-js). Hope this helps !